# HTTP request Post to a Server where HTTP body is a JSON dictionary

Tags: android, json, http, post, server

I have a server I need to POST an http request to. The server is located at http://ec2-54-187-236-58.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com

I need to execute a POST /ios/search

I'm given that the HTTP body is a JSON dictionary but I cannot connect to the server itself. Nor am I able to see the JSON object in javascript when I enter the server url in a browser. I am using gson library in android to help me execute the http client request, but am getting the

`IOException: Connection to http://ec2-54-187-236-58.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/ios/search  refused`

What am I missing? Or is there an issue with the server url?

Comment: There's an issue with the server url.

Comment: That is what I thought. Do you know what seems to be the issue with the server url? @squeeish

Comment: It's... not contactable? You need to speak to the guy in charge. Tell him you can't even ping it.